# Send multiple email batches

Tags: php

I have 100,000 email in my database and I want to send emails in the form of packages

in the first package

```
send 1000 email
stop the process 10  second " sleep function ".
```

Then in the second package

```
send 1000 email
stop the process 10  second " sleep function "
```

this my code in fact its not send email , but it send notification on mobile by "GCM";
the server timeout end after 10 minute , the process is end after 10 minute and the process is not complete .

my code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noti_code ORDER BY noti_id desc ",$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $gcmRegID = $row[noti_code];

$foo->message = $pushMessage = $_POST["message"];
$foo->link = $n_link = $_POST["n_link"];
$json = json_encode($foo);
//$result =  mysql_query("insert into notifications(n_title,n_link,n_code)values('$json','$n_link','$gcmRegID')",$link);
$id = $_POST["regId"];
if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {   
  $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
  $message = array("m" => $json);
  $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);

  }
}
```

Comment: what you had tried yet? show us that code.

Comment: What is your question?  In what way is your code not working?

Comment: post some code , and what is your question?

Comment: you could chunk it by 1000 first then after that batch then sleep

Answer (score 0):

This code should be in a for loop and changing the recipients in accordance:

```
$recipients = array(
  "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
  // more emails
);
$email_to = implode(',', $recipients); // your email address
$email_subject = "..."; // email subject line
$message = "..."; // body of the message

mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message);
sleep(10);
```